# Is it possible to display the icon of the right side of the Text in an MenuItem in the Honeycomb ActionBar?

Tags: android, menuitem, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

When i use the ActionBar i can add icons to the MenuItems as i would in earlier Android Versions. But the icons are always on the left side of the text. Can i place the icon on the right side somehow? Example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/somebutton"
        android:title="mylabel"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an action view and arrange your own custom presentation and handling of the item, but that's really not recommended in this case. Honeycomb style guidelines are to place the icons on the left.